# No difference between the platforms using ionic 3

Tags: android, ios, typescript, ionic-framework, difference

I wanted to try ionic 3, but I have some issues at the beginning. When I start the application with the `ionic lab` or the `ionic serve` command, when the browser shows the platforms, the views are the same on every device (ios, android, windows)

Although if I set `IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)` to `IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {mode: 'ios'})` in the `app.module.ts` it changes to iOS view on all the devices, or if I set to `IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {mode: 'md'})` it changes to Android on all the devices. But when I start the application with the default code every device shows the same view, and I never could reach the devices to show their own views.

[Here you can see the default operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSZ7w.png)

[And here when I sterted with `IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {mode: 'ios'})` command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeovR.png)

Are there any idea why doesn't work as in all the videos I saw on the internet? Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the URL you are opening, here's my best guess: Try opening

http://localhost:8100/ionic-lab

rather than http://localhost:8200. Worked for me in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an issue with your installation of ionic? Try uninstalling Ionic & Cordova, clearing the cache and updating NPM. Then reinstall everything. Use the following commands:

```
npm uninstall ionic cordova

npm cache clean -f

npm install -g npm

npm install -g ionic cordova
```